# How to encrypt the Data in swift3? When I m encrypting the data and printing it .it is showing me in Bytes .I have use RNCryptor

Tags: swift

String to Data:

```
let ciphertext = RNCryptor.encrypt(data: testString.data(using: 
              String.Encoding.utf8)!, withPassword: password)


print(ciphertext)
```

Back to string:

```
var backToString = String(data: ciphertext, encoding: 
                 String.Encoding.utf8) as String!


print(backToString)
```

Comment: you should RNCryptor.decrypt first before converting to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For decryption employ `RNCryptor.decrypt()` method, not default `String(data: ..)`.

```
// Decryption
do {
    let originalData = try RNCryptor.decrypt(data: ciphertext, withPassword: password)
    // ...
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

And then manipulate the original data as you do it:

```
var backToString = String(data: originalData, encoding: 
                 String.Encoding.utf8) as String!


print(backToString)
```

Comment: It is working.Now i have to make Addition of that ciphert without decrypting it .like      var a = cipher + number .Number is in String format .When i m doing this .it is showing me error like binary operands cannot be apply on String and Data.

Comment: From what you refer - and if I understood correctly - you are trying to cipher (encrypt) a string and then you want to add something to it "without decrypting". If this is what you want, then this devaluates the meaning of encryption as such. You encrypt to avoid original data being easily accessed, otherwise why encrypt in the first place?